# Replace Newline character, Backspace character and carriage return character in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file with 3 columns with data in every column. The data is in format below :

Every field is enclosed with backspaces like: BSC123BSC (here BSC is a backspace character). Columns' values contain new line and carriage return characters.
Columns are delimited by Escape character.

I am not able to find the regex pattern to replace all three mentioned characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `[\b\n\r]` should work.

```
>>> data = spark.createDataFrame([('086261636b73706163650d43520a4c4608',),('080d0a08',)],['hexstring']).withColumn('col',decode(unhex('hexstring'),'UTF-8')).drop('hexstring')
>>> cleansed = data.withColumn('regexed',regexp_replace('col','[\b\n\r]','*'))                                                              
>>> cleansed.select('regexed').show()
+-----------------+                                                             
|          regexed|
+-----------------+
|*backspace*CR*LF*|
|             ****|
+-----------------+

>>>
```